# C# - Store variables and user settings (number of variables and settings is not predefined)

Tags: c#, variables, store

I am working on an application (using C#) which has many classes. Each user may produce different number of sets for each class, for example:

> user 1: 2 sets of Class1, 1 set of Class2, and 3 sets of Class3.
>
> user 2: 1 set  of Class1, 3 sets of Class2, and 1 set of Class3.

Then, the application do analysis based on these settings.

I am looking for a direct method to store these settings (i.e. all newly produced variables) and later, load and use (or set) them, or interactively have access  (reading and setting, i.e. direct access to the variable) at run time from anywhere in the application. Speed is not of my concern.

I know about *Properties.Settings* but as far as unknown number of variables are produced by user, it is not the appropriate method (which stores predefined variables!).

It is about two days that I am googling and searching in StackOverflow, but I couldn't find a direct method.

What is the best method (the most routine method) to store and access variables and use them at run time or load later, **XML serialization**, **SQLite local database** or ...? and How?

Thanks for your time.

**ADDED:**

Also, please consider these cases:

1- User may changes the value of variables at run time, so a direct access to the stored variable is favored.

2- The user must not be involved in installing any external libraries, contents, or third party applications. Everything should be installed with my application.

3- Stored data are not only for showing purposes, but also for processing, so we deal with any type of variables, e.g. bool, int, float, double, decimal, string, etc.

4- Store/load multiple sets of variables (with different types) belong to a class.

5- Overall objectives:

- store previously and newly created data interactively and dynamically
- direct access to stored data at runtime and ability to change them
- load data at start
- direct access to data anywhere in the application

Comment: Do all these classes share a base class or an interface?

Comment: They are different classes with/without an interface.

Comment: So you have a `List<MyInterface> allClasses` or some object that holds multiple lists for all classes that the user instancitated? If that's the case you could whenever needed this root list / object serialize into a string and write it into a file. On start you read that file and deserialize it as the root list / object.

Comment: You have a `List<MyInterface>` that contains all instances and you serialize that list.

Comment: Thanks. I will try JSON for saving/loading lists.

Answer (score 0):

If the variables and settings are dynamic in nature for each user, I would go with storing them in **Json** format and store it in database. This makes the application flexible.

In your case, you mentioned that the each user may produce different number of sets of each class, try storing in Json format.

Comment: Thanks. By Json, may I directly access variables at run time? Please note that loading the variables at start is not adequate for me, I should directly access them (read and set) at run time too.

Comment: In general yes, you should be able to load/read the settings and variables from database at run-time.

Comment: If you have a database, why serialize it as JSON? Also a DB needs a Server where the database is hosted. I would it probably also save it as JSON, but in a file, not in a DB.

Comment: @Oliver, An SQLite DB does not need server, the DB stores data in a local space. Do you suggest using JSON in my case?

Comment: Does JSON support storing and loading a set of variables like a class? and also multiple copies of a class (a set of variables) as multiple set of variables?